# How to find the pre-image of a relation given the interval?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\begin{array}{l}
> \text { 2) Given the following relations: } \\
> \qquad f=\left\{(x, y) \text { , } x, y \in Z, y=x^{4}+4\right\}, \text { a relation from } Z \text { to } Z \text { . }
> \end{array}\\
> &\begin{array}{l|l}
> \mathrm{g}=\{(x, y) & \left.x, y \in \mathbf{R}, x^{2}+y^{2}=4\right\}, \text { a relation from } \mathbf{R} \text { to } \mathbf{R} . \\
> \mathrm{h}=\{(x, y) & \left.x, y \in \mathbf{R}, x^{2}=y-1\right\}, \text { a relation from } \mathbf{R} \text { to } \mathbf{R} .
> \end{array}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> $$
> \text { c) For each of } f, g, \text { and } h, \text { find the preimage of the interval } B=[-2,2]
> $$

Can someone please explain how to find the pre-image of the interval $B[-2,2]$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, in the first case, you are looking for all integers $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $-6\leq x^4\leq -2$, which is clearly the empty set. In the second case, $g^{-1}([-2,2])$ is the set of all real numbers $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x, \pm\sqrt{4-x^2})$ is a point of the circle of radius $2$ around the origin, hence $x\in[-2,2]$. As for $h$, the closed interval $[-1,1]$ will work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However, I still don't understand why for h, the answer is [-1,1]. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: $y=x^2+1$, that is a parable with vertex at the origin and translated +1 along $y$-axis